# Traverse through list of dictionaries and get latest vale

Tags: python

If I have input like below:

```
metadata = [{"id": 123, "timestamp": 12, "meta": "e"},
            {"id": 123, "timestamp": 24, "meta": "a"},
            {"id": 124, "timestamp": 2, "meta": "d"},
            {"id": 124, "timestamp": 1, "meta": "c"}]
```

I want the output to be another list of dictionaries which will give the latest record by timestamp for every ID. In this case -

```
[{"id": 123, "timestamp": 24, "meta": "a"}, {"id": 124, "timestamp": 2, "meta": "d"}]
```

I reached a point where I was able to sort the list based on ID and timestamp using -

```
k = sorted(metadata, key=lambda x: (x['id'], x['timestamp']))
```

But I am stuck after this on picking only the first record per ID.

Comment: If you need to do lots of this kind of thing, I recommend you learn about pandas.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `pandas`:

```
from itertools import groupby

k = sorted(metadata, key=lambda x: (x['id'], x['timestamp']))
result = [list(g)[-1] for k, g in groupby(k, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks a ton!